# Comparing two csv files using Python and find similar values in two file and save the similar values in another file as matching values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to find similar records in two csv files. One csv file has 9 columns in it, while the second may also have the same. The table can be viewed at

1) [DHU_Table](http://acm.dhu.edu.cn/solution/list.html?loginId=)

2) [HDU_Table](http://acm.hdu.edu.cn/status.php)

But only few columns are related. Like

```
Results---Judge Status,
When----Submit Time,
Language-----Language,
Time----Exe.Time,
```

How to use only these specific column for comparison?

Comment: your links don't help, like _at all_

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the first website can be log-in using 315034 as user name and password.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a link](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/using-the-csv-module-in-python/) that might help. Once you figure out how to read CSV files (or parse the data yourself) you can then make a class which contains all the information from a row of the CSV file. For example if you have AGE and NAME as the two columns you can make a class that contains age and name.

```
class Row:
    def __init__ (self, AGE, NAME):
        self.name = NAME
        self.age = AGE
```

Once you gather all the information from both files (by for example storing the classes in a list) you can then write an algorithm to compare the classes and find similarities for example:

```
def compareName (row1, row2):
    return (row1.name == row2.name)
```

Comment: i am quite new to python programming so its a little bit hard for me understand at the moment,anyway thanks for your reply and suggestions.By the way i am looking to find full python code.